# Returning new instance of class in own constructor

Tags: typescript, prisma

I was reading the Prisma ORM source code, and happened upon [this snippet](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/ed57e142b886418cce624c87e23b281ce647d200/packages/migrate/src/commands/MigrateDev.ts#L35-L38):

```
export class MigrateDev implements Command {
  public static new(): MigrateDev {
    return new MigrateDev()
  }
  
  ...
```

I'm very confused. How does returning a new instance of the class in its very own constructor result in anything but an infinite loop and stack overflow?

Comment: ...that's **not** its constructor (note it's static, and not named [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)).

Comment: Wow, I must have been experiencing extreme code fatigue when reading this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, that's not the constructor. That's simply a static/class method called `new` as javascript allows to use restricted keywords like this.

In that specific case, `MigrateDev.new()` would be equivalent to `new MigrateDev()`.